# Ubuntu Desktop Installation type

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb, live-usb

I finally managed to make a usb to boot another pc that's OS(Win10) the best i can tell has been completely corrupted. Have now begun the installation and I am asked "What I would like to do?" since the PC currently has Windows Boot Manager on it. I do not want to delete all programs, docs, photos, etc, since ultimately was hoping on retrieving that data by using Ubuntu. So, I select the "Something else" allowing me to create or resize partitions myself, or choose multiple partitions for Ubuntu. Now I don't know what to do from here. Any help would be appreciated.  I found an instruction on here but it was for windows 7 and the photos and explanation leaving me somewhat unsure of what I needed to do. Thank you

Comment: If you need to (try to) recover data from the installed Windows use the live session. Do not install Ubuntu. If you can boot Windows and do it from there even better.

Comment: There's a reason why what you found is mostly about Windows 7 and older. Since Windows 8 the default behavior with fastboot is to hibernate all NTFS partitions and when those are somehow corrupted the chances of recovering data with Linux tools is slim to none.

Comment: I would suggest googling "Windows 10 Repair tools" before trying a Ubuntu based solution.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm fairly new to this. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

With the ubuntu bootable USB select the option **Try ubuntu without installation.** Then I believe you can access files of windows OS from there, now attach other USB stick/portable hard drive and copy all your important files.

Comment: I'm going to give this a shot and see how it turns out. Thanks